# Is the object data type static in Python?

Tags: python, object, pandas, type-conversion

I have a data frame which contains two columns: one with strings and the other with integers. As expected, the data type of the integer column is `int64`. For the string column, however, it is `object`.

Now I wanted to convert the string column to an integer column by assigning each string a given integer. I do so as follows:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

# Create a data frame with two columns:
# - `catCol' represents categorical data and consists of strings
# - `intCol' represents numerical data and consists of integers
myList = {'catCol': ['NM', 'VT', 'VA', 'NY', 'VA'], 'intCol': [3, 6, 10, -1, 0]}
df = DataFrame(myList)

print('Before the mapping:')
print(df)
print('Data type of `catCol`:', df['catCol'].dtype)
print('Data type of a `catCol` element:', type(df['catCol'][3]))
print('Data type of `intCol`:', df['intCol'].dtype)
print('Data type of a `intCol` elements:', type(df['intCol'][3]))

# Replace the categorical columns with unique integers IDs.
fromList = df['catCol'].unique()
toList = list(range(len(fromList)))

for idx in range(len(fromList)):
    df.loc[df['catCol'] == fromList[idx], 'catCol'] = toList[idx]

print()
print('After the mapping:')
print(df)    
print('Data type of `catCol`:', df['catCol'].dtype)
print('Data type of a `catCol` element:', type(df['catCol'][3]))
print('Data type of `intCol`:', df['intCol'].dtype)
print('Data type of a `intCol` elements:', type(df['intCol'][3]))
```

The output is:

```
Before the mapping:
  catCol  intCol
0     NM       3
1     VT       6
2     VA      10
3     NY      -1
4     VA       0
Data type of `catCol`: object
Data type of a `catCol` element: <class 'str'>
Data type of `intCol`: int64
Data type of a `intCol` elements: <class 'numpy.int64'>

After the mapping:
  catCol  intCol
0      0       3
1      1       6
2      2      10
3      3      -1
4      2       0
Data type of `catCol`: object
Data type of a `catCol` element: <class 'int'>
Data type of `intCol`: int64
Data type of a `intCol` elements: <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

**Here comes the problem:** If the transformed `catCol` now contains only integers, why is it still an object data type? I need it to be an integer data type, just like `intCol`. How can I fix do this *without* using any cast?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, actually `object` type means strings or a mixture of numeric and NaNs (Not a Number) values in numpy/pandas

Answer (score 0):

i would use [map()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) function in this case:

```
In [84]: toList = pd.Series(range(len(df['catCol'].unique())), index=df['catCol'].unique())

In [85]: toList
Out[85]:
NM    0
VT    1
VA    2
NY    3
dtype: int32

In [86]: df.catCol.map(toList)
Out[86]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    2
Name: catCol, dtype: int32

In [87]: df['catCol'] = df.catCol.map(toList)

In [88]: df
Out[88]:
   catCol  intCol
0       0       3
1       1       6
2       2      10
3       3      -1
4       2       0

In [89]: df.dtypes
Out[89]:
catCol    int32
intCol    int64
dtype: object
```